# Confused about Paypal SDK's steps to integrate into Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm trying to use [PayPal's REST API](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) to integrate the Paypal package into my Laravel application, but I'm coming unstuck on one of their steps, and there seems to be no documentation about how to do so.

I've downloaded and installed the package with composer, but this step:

```
* Copy the sample configuration file sdk_config.ini to a location of your choice and let the SDK know your config path using the following define directive.

define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', /path/to/your/sdk_config.ini);
```

is confusing. I've located the sample config file, but I'm unsure of the best place to put it in my laravel project, and I'm also unsure of where to place the define PHP command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often put common 3-rd party INI config files inside the `app/config` directory and add the `define` statement inside the `app/start/global.php` like this:

```
if (!defined('PP_CONFIG_PATH')) 
{
    define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', app_path('config') . "/sdk_config.ini");
}
```